The products chosen in form UrunStokGiris does not appear in dgvStokGiris in StokGiris form
I have created two forms StokGiris and UrunStokGiris (this one is like a sub form) on first form when you click search products the sub form opens then you are able to pick whatever you want from the after choosing each they should appear in the datagridview (dgvStokGiris) in StokGiris form. The UrunStokGiris and the products that are saved in database work flawless and I have made a diagram for most of the necessary tables and a view in database. However, when you pick a product it does not appear in dgvStokGiris.
Here is the dgvStokGiris part in StokGiris form
public void LoadStokGiris()
{
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        dgvStokGiris.Rows.Clear();

        baglanti.Open();
        komut = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM vwStokGiris WHERE refno LIKE '" + txtRefNo.Text + "' AND durum LIKE 'Beklemede'", baglanti);

        dr = komut.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            i++;
            dgvStokGiris.Rows.Add(i, dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString(), dr[6].ToString(), dr[7].ToString());
        }

        dr.Close();
        baglanti.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Hata: " + ex.Message, pbaslik, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
   }
}

Here is a part of UrunStokGiris that is also connected to the other form
private void dgvUrun_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string colName = dgvUrun.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;

    if (colName == "Sec")
    {
        if (stokGiris.txtStokGiren.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Lütfen stoğu girecek kişiyi yazın", pbaslik, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            stokGiris.txtStokGiren.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (MessageBox.Show("Bu ürün eklenecek?", pbaslik, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult)

            try
            {
                baglanti.Open();
                komut = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbStokGiris (refno, ukodu, starih, stokgiren, tedarikid) VALUES (@refno, u/ukodu, u/starih, u/stokgiren, u/tedarikid)", baglanti);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refno", stokGiris.txtRefNo.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ukodu", dgvUrun.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starih", stokGiris.stokGirisTarih.Value);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stokgiren", stokGiris.txtStokGiren.Text);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tedarikid", stokGiris.etktId.Text);
                komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                baglanti.Close();
                stokGiris.LoadStokGiris();
            }
            catch()
            {}   
    }
}

I have recreated the table, diagram and view in SQL Server, I have also added try catch method to catch any issues related however it did not work.

Fixed the issue by adding (.Yes) to Message Box in dgvUrun_CellContentClick
if (MessageBox.Show("Bu ürün eklenecek?", pbaslik, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)

Note: there was also a mistake on database in Views where tbStokGiris.id = dbo.tbTedarik.id while the correct one was tbStokGiris.tedarikid = dbo.tbTedarik.id.
